# Cypress: You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, cypress, cypress-cucumber-preprocessor

I'm an automation engineer trying to configure a cypress test inside an existing react application but I keep getting this error:

> Webpack Compilation Error
> ./cypress/e2e/googleSearch.feature 1:16
> Module parse failed: Unexpected token (1:16)
> You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
> Feature: Google Search

My feature file is located under:
`/Users/francislainycampos/IdeaProjects/hello-talk-web/cypress/e2e/googleSearch.feature`

My steps file is under:
`/Users/francislainycampos/IdeaProjects/hello-talk-web/cypress/e2e/spec/googleSearch.spec.js`

My `plugins/index.js` file has this:

```javascript
const cucumber = require('cypress-cucumber-preprocessor').default
module.exports = (on, config) => {
    on('file:preprocessor', cucumber())
}
```

And my package json file has these versions:

```json
 "devDependencies": {
    "cypress": "^12.11.0",
    "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": "^4.3.1",
    "@cypress/webpack-preprocessor": "^5.17.1",
  },
  "cypress-cucumber-preprocessor": {
    "nonGlobalStepDefinitions": true
  }
```

My `cypress.config.js` has:

```javascript
const {defineConfig} = require("cypress");

module.exports = defineConfig({
    e2e: {
        setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
            // implement node event listeners here
        },
        specPattern: "/Users/francislainycampos/IdeaProjects/hello-talk-web/cypress/e2e/googleSearch.feature",

        // integrationFolder: "cypress/e2e",
        supportFile: "cypress/support/commands.js",
    },
});
```

This is my project on Github:
https://github.com/francislainy/hello-talk-web/tree/cucumber

I attempted to address this by creating a `webpack.config.js` file under the root of the project as below, but still getting the same error.

```javascript
module.exports = {
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.feature$/,
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'cypress-cucumber-webpack-preprocessor/loader',
                    },
                ],
            },
        ],
    },
};
```

Comment: I'm lost, are you using `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` from https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/docs/quick-start.md ?

Comment: To configure Cypress, I invite you to check this repository that implements it https://github.com/wandri/chat-spring-kafka-angular-react-vue

Comment: Cypress cucumber processor was installed with ```npm install --save-dev cypress cypress-cucumber-preprocessor```

Comment: I tried now with the other preprocessor you suggested, but the error is still the same.

Comment: `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` is not anymore updated. The package was migrated to `github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`. Please use it instead

Comment: I get the same error with that too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a "hybrid" system that needs updating, although I recommend starting fresh to make it easier.

- `plugins/index.js` this is from a Cypress 9 setup and is no longer used. You *could* use it but why make life difficult?
- `cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` is defunct, remove it and install `github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor`
- the configuration for `github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor` is inside `cypress.config.js` and is given in the documentation. I recommend [this one](https://github.com/badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/blob/master/examples/esbuild-cjs/cypress.config.js)

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const createBundler = require("@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor");
const preprocessor = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor");
const createEsbuildPlugin = require("@badeball/cypress-cucumber-preprocessor/esbuild");

async function setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
  await preprocessor.addCucumberPreprocessorPlugin(on, config);

  on(
    "file:preprocessor", createBundler({
      plugins: [createEsbuildPlugin.default(config)],
    })
  );

  return config;
}

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    specPattern: "**/*.feature",
    setupNodeEvents,
  },
})
```

- add dependency `@bahmutov/cypress-esbuild-preprocessor`

Comment: By the way, I also needed to put my steps definitions inside the support folder. I've added all the code here with the sample to load the google page in case it may be useful to someone else. https://github.com/francislainy/debug-cypress